# Back button solution after logout?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, logout

So, i'm working on a web application project at work. I'm using Spring MVC, Hibernate, Jsp technologies in my project. I was facing an issue regarding logout. Issue was when a user logout and then presses back button in the browser the secure page was compromised. I looked for solutions on the internet and even asked for help from senior developers in know, the solution i found was not complete "solution was to set headers in secure pages to no-cache etc". But there was a issue with this solution when the user hits browsers back button after he/she logout this error was shown in chrome browser.
[image]

and when the user refreshes the page this error was shown
[image]

and if the user refreshes the page again he/she will be taken to the login page.
So this was not user friendly. yesterday i found something interesting. I worked a solution for duplicate form submission and that ended up the solution for logout issue.
So, im gonna provide solution as an answer to this question. As i spent days to solve this i dont want anyone to do the same im providing a solution to this problem and if possible i'll provide a demo project for download.
Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is the solution.
First of all add the following lines of code in your secure jsp pages.
[image]

Now, add a redirect in controller method like this.
[image]

and now, your logout controller method should look like this.
[image]

That's it. Now when the user hits browsers back button after logging out he will be taken to the login page, and no secure page will be compromised.

Please give feedback if this helps.

OR else
You may want to take a look at servlet filters.

Comment: Don't add the code to your pages... Spring Security already disables caching by default (if that isn't working you are working around Spring Security). Also your login and logout function is again working around Spring Security. Instead of working around the framework I suggest to actually start using the framework. This basically is a solution by, instead of working with the framework is working around the framework.

Comment: I think this solution can apply to jsp/servlet projects also and may be to other server side scripting languages. I was just sharing the logic how to solve the back button issue. Nothing to do with spring or any specific language.

Comment: The tags and your post suggest otherwise. Nonetheless you don't want to add that header to each and every page... You want to solve that in a generic way, something like with a servlet filter instead.

Comment: So, should i remove the tags and technologies mentioned.

Comment: Does spring security resolve the back button issue completely.

Comment: If you redirect after logout (which by default it does) yes it does.

Comment: im just begginer in spring hibernate. And this is my first project in spring. I havent covered spring security yet. Thats why i posted it to help begginers. I think it will surely help someone.
I have read many solutions on forums but none seem to provide perfect solution to my problem. Also we can add headers code to an empty jsp file and then include that file in every secure page.